# SQL procedure return codes when column mismatch occurs on INSERT statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, exception, stored-procedures

I have a 'driver' stored procedure that execute several procedures in a specific order. There is some error checking in this driver that checks the return code of the procedure that was executed and if it is not equal to 0 then it terminates. Some sample code below:

```
...
EXECUTE @return_status = data_validate

IF @return_status <> 0
BEGIN
    SELECT  return_status = 'FAIL',
            return_msg    = 'URS Data Validation Failed !!'
    PRINT  'Data validation failed!'
    RETURN 16
END
...
```

Inside this `data_validate` procedure there are some table inserts. I accidentally modified the structure of one of these tables after I had complied `data_validate`. If I had recompiled the procedure it would have given me an error, but that never happened. So the next time this driver procedure ran it executed `data_validate` and it threw the error below:

> Msg 213, Level 16, State 1, Procedure PERSONS_AFI, Line 19
>   Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.

But the return code was still 0 so my driver procedure continued and moved on to the next procedure. I understand this is probably just how TSQL handles this kind of situation, but does anyone know why? Why would the return code still be 0 even when there was an error in the procedure? That does not seem right. I know this error should have been caught at compile time, but the table was only modified after the procedure was compiled. How would I write this driver to catch an error like this?

Thank you!

Edit: This is in a huge system, so ideally I'm looking for some small tweak to the error catching IF statement in the code above. I'm not really in a position to re-work the whole thing right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the SQL stored procedure fails with a non-fatal error, then the @return_status value may not be set and is probably not 0...it may be NULL.

You should be able to modify your error check logic to add a NULL check:

```
IF ISNULL(@return_status,1) <> 0
```

Otherwise, you can edit your stored procedures to look for the @@ERROR code that gets set typically after errors in INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE statements.

UPDATE:
Neither of the following SQL will ever return data.  For NULLs you have to use "IS NULL" and "IS NOT NULL".  Or handle NULL checks specifically.

```
IF NULL = 0
    SELECT 1
IF NULL <> 0
    SELECT 1
```

Comment: You're right. @return_status is NULL. So `IF @return_status <> 0` doesn't return True?? Last I checked NULL <> 0, but maybe not according to SQL?

Also, shouldn't it be something like `IF ISNULL(@return_status,1) <> 0`  so that way when @return_status is NULL it will set it to 1 and thus not be equal to 0 and trigger the error?

Comment: Correct.  You cannot do = or <> checks with NULL.  That's one of the reasons why you have "IS NULL" and "IS NOT NULL".  See my last comment on checking NULLs.  And yes, it should be ISNULL(@return_status,1)<>0.  updated.